# Symfony2 : how to force a routing parameter not in pattern?

Tags: symfony, routes

I want to add a parameter *xyz* to some routing rules, but this parameter is not specified in pattern, as follow:

```
homepage:
    pattern:   /
    defaults:  { _controller: MyBundle:Page:home, xyz: true }

contact:
    pattern:   /contact
    defaults:  { _controller: MyBundle:Page:contact }

gallery:
    pattern:   /gallery
    defaults:  { _controller: MyBundle:Page:gallery, xyz: true }
```

I tried this routing configuration but my parameter *xyz* is not posted when calling *homepage* or *gallery* URL.

Here is my Twig page (for example):

```
...
<a href="{{ path('gallery') }}">my test link</a>
...
```

The result is:

```
<a href="/gallery">my test link</a>
```

And I was excepting that when I click on this link, my *xyz* parameter to be sent.

Any idea why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `attributes` parameter bag instead of the *GET* one

```
$request->attributes->get('xyz')
```

Comment: Your answer shows me that my question was not clear enough. So I just edited it to make it more complete.

Comment: Well, what do you want to know? How to change the route's pattern so the data can be sent? pattern: /gallery/{xyz}

Comment: I already tried this... Even if I change the pattern as you say, the result in my Twig page is the same, no mention of my xyz parameter.

Comment: The "defaults" section in the route defines the values for the corresponding fields if they are not provided by request. To pass actual value in the link you have to use the next variant: {{ path('gallery', {'xyz': 'some_value'}) }}

Comment: Ok, I was wondering if it was possible to define this in the routing files directly, not in the Twig files... thanks for your answer !

Answer (score 0):

If you add $xyz to your controller action method signature, $xyz will be present and accessible.

`public function homeAction($xyz) {
  // Code goes here
}`

`public function galleryAction($xyz) {
   // Code goes here
}`